# Certified 0,15m CAT6a cable - what to expect?

Tags: layer1, cabling

We are thinking of patching our new network rack using 0,15m cables due to costs and cable management requirements. There will be around 400-500 connections using this cable length and we will be using Dell enterprise equipment (switches). I found a vendor selling certified cables for CAT6a.

My question is in regards to [this source](https://www.clnet-solution.com/is-there-a-minimum-length/) from 2015:

> If you are talking specifically about patch cords, then 0.5 m is the implied minimum length in ANSI/TIA/EIA-568-B.2-1 for a certified patch cord. That’s because the math for the limit lines really does not work below this. Infact, getting a certified patch cord of 0.5 is going to be tricky. Many vendors only offer a certified patch cord of 1.0 m or longer.

What problems should we expect / make sure to test for before hand?

Note: The patch cables will be used to connect the patch panel with the switch

Comment: Are you *sure* you want cables that short? If it's certified, then it's certified -- as long as you trust that vendor.

Comment: @Ricky no, but unfortunately the decision is ultimately out of my hands, I'm just trying to make sure (as much as possible) this whole thing doesn't backfire. Maybe even collect a few reasons to pass on so we will use a different cable length.

Comment: You could also use proper cable management hooks and trays, and simply select one standard cable length.

Comment: @RonMaupin That was my suggestion (using cable management trays), unfortunately I "lost" due to price aspects.

Comment: Well, being cheap on something so important can certainly backfire and cost much more in the long run. Cabling infrastructure is expensed, not amortized, and accountants like that.

Comment: Are there any "hard facts" or documented use cases I could bring into the discussion concerning the cable length that would compel the responsible role to consider other directions?

Comment: In any case, there is a lot of crap sold for cabling, and you really need to deal with a proven, trusted vendor. Having a single cable length makes stocking the cables a lot easier. I wonder if other practices were ignored, such as the standards required 10' service loop on each end if a horizontal cable, pull strings in the horizontal cable paths, etc.

Comment: Possibly, I will have to get more information on that.

Comment: If you go with 6" cables, you're **committed** to keeping the switches immediately next to the patch ports. It gets very ugly working with such a wall of tiny cords. Replacing a switch - which you will have to do some day - will be a royal pain. (I wouldn't suggest it, but if they're that cheap, why not just crimp the wires instead of going to a patch panel.)

Comment: @Ricky Having the patch panel right next to the switch is the current plan. Why is replacing the switch with short cables more difficult then with long cables? As far as I can imagine you have to unplug them regardless of the length, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: With short cables, every one has to be disconnected before the switch can be removed. With longer cables, the switch can be pulled, new switch mounted, *and then* move all the connections. 6" cables may seem like a good idea, but trust us, it isn't. (plus, that will be all those cables will *ever* be useful for.)

Comment: Thanks Ricky, I'll keep that in mind. Availability is not an 24/7 but a "working hour" issue at our site so hopefully this won't be too much of a problem. I think I will just have to ride it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**
If the cables goes into a patch panel, the cable length is equal to the sum of the cable lengths on each side of the patch panel.

Comment: Good point! They actually do, I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most known vendors now have length detection on their switch/router firmware which adjusts signaling power and timing accordingly. Based on years of experience, I believe you'll have little to zero issues working with short cables in compact server rooms.

It is still a good policy to stick to ratified cables, anyhow.

Comment: With the notable exception of 2.5GBASE-T and 5GBASE-T, that isn't necessarily true. Standard ports perform *no* cable quality and power training. Only ports featuring *Green Ethernet* (a superset of EEE) actually optimize signaling (EEE optimizes idle link power only).

Comment: I wasn't talking about green networking specifically, but thanks for useful comment.